# Simultaneous Celery tasks sharing a common object (a DB connection)

Tags: python, concurrency, celery, cx-oracle

I'm working with Python, Celery, and cx_Oracle.

I launch a bunch of workers. These workers share a database connection object.

This is how I create the database connection object (`db_conn`). Note the `threaded=True` paramenter:

```
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=db_user,
                            password=db_password,
                            dsn=dsn,
                            threaded=True)
```

The tasks being run by these workers consist mainly on executing some queries which take several seconds to complete. The chances of several workers overlapping in time (concurrency) is quite high.

My question is: should I take any special measure when sharing the database connection object (`db_conn`)?

Does Celery automatically take care of these things? I mean, if a task is using the database connection object, will Celery make any other task wait till the first worker has finished running? If no, then how could I allow each worker to use the database connection object only when no other worker is using it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure you know what happens when one of the queries fails. Does each new query start its own transaction? You need to sure that the db connection is being properly closed when you're done with it, but not before that point.

Is there a real reason that you need to share this db connection between workers? One db connection per celery worker is much simpler to implement, easier to maintain, less prone to bugs and gives you more control over opening/ closing connections. Then you can deal with the concurrency issues in python instead of hoping your database connection lets things through in the correct order.